# How to save part of image in arrays or matrices in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, image-processing, matrix, computer-vision

I am developing a project of detecting vehicles' headlights in night scene. I am working on a demo on MATLAB. My problem is that I need to find region of interest (ROI) to get low computing requirement. My solution is calculating total intensity per row and if the row's intensity is below threshold, it is blacked.

```
[rows col] = size(img1);
sumValue=[];
sum1 = sum(sum(img1)/(rows*col));
for a=1:1:rows
    sumValue = sum(img1(a,:))/col;
    if (sumValue <sum1+40)   
        img1(a,:)=0;
    end
end
```

And here is the result:

[image]

Now i want to save the bright parts of image in arrays or matrices so that i can delete the small bright parts and keep only large part. If anyone has any idea, plz give me some suggestions.

Comment: Either store the row numbers to be removed somewhere and delete them after the loop ends. Or get the rows to be removed using row-wise sum and detect if the sums are zero and remove them using logical indexing  like this - `img1(sum(img,2)==0,:)=[];`

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but a suggestion: you can cut down on your ROI by working in a different color space that gives importance to the brightness of the headlights.

You can try to separate them from the remaining image.
I'll leave it to you to figure out what color space to choose and to incorporate this into your current code depending on the time/motivation you have. Further, you can binarize this result by setting a threshold. Then pick the ROI and use these indices to form your ROI.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this could be optimised a bit more.

```
new_im = zeros(size(im));

% Loop through each column
for c=1:1:size(im,2)
    column = im(:,c);

    % The first non-zero value in each column will be the top of the window
    upper_candidates = find(column>0); 
    top = upper_candidates(1);

    % The first zero value after that will be your lower boundary
    lower_candidates = find(column(top:end) == 0);
    bottom = lower_candidates(1);

    % Insert each column into the new image
    new_im = im(top:bottom,c);  
end
```